# Where to enable cors?

Tags: tomcat, cors, tomcat7

I have a very basic question.

I have an application `www.myapp1.com` hosted on tomcat server. It in turn calls apis hosted on `myapis.com/api1` on apache server.

While loading the page, it breaks stating -

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load myapis.com/api1. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'www.myapp1.com' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 403.

I understand I have to enable CORS. My question is which server do I enable CORS on? Should it be `www.myapp1.com` or `myapis.com/api1`?

I tried enabling CORS on `www.myapp1.com`, which is a tomcat7.0.59 server by adding the minimal filter (below) to /config/web.xml file and restarting the server. However, it is not working. Do I need to add/configure anything else?

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is the wildcard in url-pattern causing a problem? Do I have to do anything to setup the filter-class?

I am using chrome to test. 
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS on a Wordpress Subdomain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378729/how-to-enable-cors-on-a-wordpress-subdomain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default value](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html) of `cors.exposed.headers` is `""`. Add this parameter could fix the issue.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: I have now added the init-params as mentioned in the advanced configuration http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Comment: No change. When I am looking at Dev Tools->Network in Chrome, I can see the following irrespective of whether I have CORS filter enabled. 

OPTIONS /api1 HTTP/1.1
Host: myapis.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://myapp1.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: https://myapp1.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: What error do you see in **Dev Tools -> Console**? If the error is the same as before, please check the <param-value> again, it is case sensitive.

Comment: I forget most important thing. The setting of CORS filter must add to `myapis.com/api1`